# Xslt sort numbers

Tags: sorting, xslt, numbers

I'm trying to sort some number but I'm having someproblem with the sort.

1. The rep_Tool/@ToolStnNo is a node that give me a number of a tool in any order.

For example:

```
    ...
    <ToolStnNo>
    10
    </ToolStnNo>
    ...
    <ToolStnNo>
    12
    </ToolStnNo>
    ...
    <ToolStnNo>
    3
    </ToolStnNo>
    ...
    <ToolStnNo>
    11
    </ToolStnNo>
    ...
    <ToolStnNo>
    2
    </ToolStnNo>
    ...
    <ToolStnNo>
    4
    </ToolStnNo>
    ...
    <ToolStnNo>
    1
    </ToolStnNo>
    ...
    <ToolStnNo>
    6
    </ToolStnNo>
    ...
    <ToolStnNo>
    5
    </ToolStnNo>
    ...
    <ToolStnNo>
    8
    </ToolStnNo>
    ...
    <ToolStnNo>
    7
    </ToolStnNo>
    ...
```

The result table that I'm getting is:

```
10   --- > This 10 dont be here
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
11
12
13
```

And the right is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
10   --- > This 10 should be here
11
12
13
```

```xml
    <xsl:for-each select="MillSetupSheetAttr">
        <xsl:for-each select="MillOperation"> 
            <xsl:sort select="rep_Tool/@ToolStnNo" data-type="number"/>
            <tr>
                <td><font><xsl:value-of select="rep_Tool/@ToolStnNo"/></font></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Note: the actual structure of the relevant part of the xml document is:

```
<MillSetupSheetAttr>
    <MillOperation>
        <rep_Tool ToolStnNo="10" .../>
    </MillOperation>
    <MillOperation>
        <rep_Tool ToolStnNo="1" .../>
    </MillOperation>
    <MillOperation>
        <rep_Tool ToolStnNo="2" .../>
    </MillOperation>
</MillSetupSheetAttr>
```

Comment: Can you show more of the xml structure - how MillSetupSheetAttr/MillOperation/rep_Tool/@ToolStnNo relate to each other.

Comment: It's a large file. Can I send you via dropbox? https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4mu1riun45h8tot/AABAZgsqXj-aPA2QoaF9nDo3a?dl=0

Comment: Give us an excerpt that shows this structure - its impossible to debug xslt if we don't know the node structure being worked with.

Comment: Download from this link. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4mu1riun45h8tot/AABAZgsqXj-aPA2QoaF9nDo3a?dl=0 Is the CW.xml

Comment: Your XML shows `ToolStnNo` as an element but the XSL is accessing it as an attribute. Which one is correct? If you want a `<tr>` per `ToolStnNo` element then wouldn't `<xsl:for-each select="MillSetupSheetAttr/MillOperation/rep_Tool/ToolStnNo"><xsl:sort select="." data-type="number"/><tr></tr></xsl:for-each>` sort as required.

Comment: I've added the required info

Comment: I dont know to much about xslt. My ToolStnNo is a element that I use to create the table and I want to sort by this element ToolStnNo.

Comment: Your problem cannot be reproduced using the posted code: http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKwx

Comment: Ok. I will try to fix it by myself. Thanks for help ;).

Comment: @BrunoDiasVasconcelos  "*I will try to fix it by myself*" I wish I could help you, but without seeing the problem I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Ok. I cloud not fix the problem. But I know what cause it. If I send you all the xslt code and the xml you can help me to sort the table?

Comment: You can download the xsl and the xml from this link. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4mu1riun45h8tot/AABAZgsqXj-aPA2QoaF9nDo3a?dl=0 Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML you have shown in your question is not representative of your actual XML (and it is important to show a representative example in your question, because otherwise when the files disappear from drop-box, the context of this question could become lost).

This would be more representative of your XML:

```
<Data>
  <MillSetupSheetAttr>
    <MillOperation>
        <rep_Tool ToolStnNo="10" .../>
    </MillOperation>
    <MillOperation>
        <rep_Tool ToolStnNo="1" .../>
    </MillOperation>
  </MillSetupSheetAttr>  
  <MillSetupSheetAttr>
    <MillOperation>
        <rep_Tool ToolStnNo="12" .../>
    </MillOperation>
    <MillOperation>
        <rep_Tool ToolStnNo="3" .../>
    </MillOperation>
  </MillSetupSheetAttr> 
</Data>
```

You have multiple `MillSetupSheetAttr` elements, and the issue you are having is because you currently have a nested `xsl:for-each`...

```
<xsl:for-each select="MillSetupSheetAttr">
    <xsl:for-each select="MillOperation"> 
        <xsl:sort select="rep_Tool/@ToolStnNo" data-type="number"/>
```

This means it will sort `MillOperation` elements within each `MillSetupSheetAttr` element separately. So, you will get the sorted `MillOperation` for the first `MillSetupSheetAttr` first, followed by the sorted `MillOperation` for the second `MillSetupSheetAttr`.

To solve this, you should combine the two `xsl:for-each` statements into one:

```
<xsl:for-each select="MillSetupSheetAttr/MillOperation"> 
    <xsl:sort select="rep_Tool/@ToolStnNo" data-type="number"/>
    <tr>
       <td><font><xsl:value-of select="rep_Tool/@ToolStnNo"/></font></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This will sort all `MillOperation` elements in one go.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new in this kind of site and xsl language is not my strong. I will consider your advice, Thanks for help my friend